# VBA Excel array error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have to generate an ID using a macro and I'm facing some problems when there are 8 numeric values required.
The ID has to include numeric values for the 1st-8th charactera and the 9th must be alphabetic. From the 10th character onwards it has to be spaces.
These are my codes and I'm certain that there are no issues with the formula

```
Function GenerateRB()

strLastCharSelections = "X,W,M,L,K,J,E,D,C,B,A"

intNumber = GenerateRandomNumber(1000000, 9999999)

ReDim a(8)
For i = 1 To 8
a(i) = Mid(intNumber, i, 1)
Next

intTotal = a(1) * 9 + a(2) * 8 + a(3) * 7 + a(4) * 6 + a(5) * 5 + a(6) * 4 + a(7) * 3 + a(8) * 2


intRemainder = intTotal Mod 11

arrstrSplitLastCharSelections = Split(strLastCharSelections, ",")
strLastChar = arrstrSplitLastCharSelections(intRemainder)
GenerateRB = intNumber & strLastChar
End Function
```

The code works when its

```
    ReDim a(7)
For i = 1 To 7
a(i) = Mid(intNumber, i, 1)
Next

intTotal = a(1) * 9 + a(2) * 8 + a(3) * 7 + a(4) * 6 + a(5) * 5 + a(6) * 4 + a(7) * 3
```

Any help will be appreciated as I'm very new to this, Thank you!

Comment: What is the error and on what line does it occur?

Comment: I think Mark has the answer for you. One interesting note, I was figuring at first you had a problem with the array, because arrays usually start at 0. VBA provides the option to base them off 1 by default, or specify any bounds you want, but the default is 0. However, I tested, and it looks like VBA lets you iterate  the array in your example as either 1 to 8 or 0 to 7, and can figure out what you're doing on the fly. However, I'd say it's dangerous to rely on it interpreting for you.

Comment: it's run time error 13, occurring on the line intTotal = a(1) * 9 ........

Comment: You can't get 8 digits out of a 7 digit number.  IntNumber will need to be an 8 digit number for your code to work.  And the code seems to work OK here with `intNumber = GenerateRandomNumber(10000000, 99999999)` where that function generates a random number between those two values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `GenerateRandomnNumber` will return a numeric in the specified range - in this case, a seven digit number between 1000000 and 9999999.

So when selecting the `i`th digit in the statement `a(i) = Mid(intNumber, i, 1)`, there are no issues when `i` is 1 to 7 - however, when it's 8 - there is no eighth digit, so the code will fail.

Comment: - Mark Wickett Is there a way to fix this?? I'm not really sure what other functions can be used to replace Mid() though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you wanted to follow your current approach, just make the numbers be 8 digits, so GenerateRandomNumber(10000000, 999999999) - You could also just pick 8 random integers between 0 and 9.

Comment: It doesn't work when the numbers is at 8 digits.. I think its due to what Mark said, as i used the Mid() function, it only works when a total of odd number digits used. Is there another function that I can use to replace Mid()?