# Running other macros with a macro based on cell's value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro which runs other macros if the value in cell "`A4`" matches. However, I'm receiving an error where a function or variable is expected. Is there any way to solve this and make the `Application.Run(Macro1)` line work?

```
Sub GenerateID()
Dim macroName As String
macroName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value

If macroName = GenerateNRIC Then
Application.Run (Macro1)
ElseIf macroName = GenerateFIN Then
Application.Run (Macro2) 
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it all depends on the values of GenerateNRIC and GenerateFIN not being equal to what you expect. Could you please add to your question how these variables are assigned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign macro in drop down list and run with button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958728/assign-macro-in-drop-down-list-and-run-with-button)

Comment: _I'm receiving an error where a function or variable is expected._. Are you sure GenerateNRIC and GenerateNRIC are actually returning a value or are declared somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that "GenerateNRIC " and "GenerateFIN" are other subs/functions.

Change this

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = GenerateNRIC Then
    Application.Run (Macro1)
ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = GenerateFIN Then
    Application.Run (Macro2) 
End If
```

to

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = GenerateNRIC Then
    call macro1
ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = GenerateFIN Then
    call Macro2 
End If
```

Or surround your `application.run (macro1)` with quotes so it would be `application.run ("Macro1")`

Comment: Theres no error but nothing is happening when i assign "GenerateID" to a button. "GenerateID" is used to run "GenerateNRIC" and "GenerateFIN", they work fine individually, just not working when i'm using "GenerateID"

Comment: What is the code for GenerateNRIC and GenerateFIN?.

Comment: The "Call" command is obsolete. When you want to Call a macro, just call it.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933841/vba-excel-array-error?noredirect=1#comment48002443_29933841)
its something like this.. sorry the code is too long i can't post it here. the difference is the formula between GenerateRB and GenerateNRIC

Comment: @MatteoNNZ it is not obsolete, if you have names that are not easy to regonise as subs/functions it is a good idea to use the call command to let anyone know that this is going to be calling a sub/function. It just makes it easier to read through. Adds nothing to performance or takes anything away but it is a good idea so you can clearly see this is going to be running a sub/function

Comment: What is the return value from the functions GenerateNRIC and GenerateFIN?

Comment: it returns a randomly generated ID

Comment: I would do breakpoints to check to make sure that it is calling that function. And that the function is returning a value so it can be checked against. And then check to see if the value in the sheet matches the value that you are getting from the functions. If it does then it might be a type conversion problem? LIke if the function is returning an array then you will need to see if the array is giving the right answer

Answer (score -1):

GenerateNRIC needs to be in quotes if it is a value in the cell

If .... = "GenerateNRIC"

This applies to both of your "if" statements.

Comment: GenerateNRIC is a seperate function, not a value in a cell.

Comment: @AmC08 It would just simply cause an error before it ran if these were not functions. As it will check that first.

Comment: That is the error the OP is getting "...I'm receiving an error where a function or variable is expected.."  Without quotes the compiler thinks GenerateNRIC is a function or undeclared variable. The if statement implies saying it is the text value in cell A4 to be processed further to trigger a macro.